# ImportError: No module named _csv . Qpython for android logs

Tags: importerror, qpython

I put goog_appengine inside android located at /mnt/sdcard
I also put wsgiref folder  at same location.
from Qpython I manage to "send control key" + "d"
I got sh $
I put command like the ff:
"$python /mnt/sdcard/google_appengine/appcfg.py"
But Igot ImportError: no module _csv

I feel putting these is not same architecture " /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_csv.x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
That come from ubuntu 13.04.

What to do next, Where I can find _csv module for Qpython+android_version.

Is it possible to upload my code through android?

Answer (score 0):

You can install _csv from QPython's system. ( You can find system icon in qpython's new version 0.9.6.2 )

Answer (score 0):

To install _csv or any other module, follow these steps.  Here's what I did to install websocket (and all of its dependencies):

To install websocket on the phone:

1. Start QPython
2. Click the big button
3. Select “run local script”
4. Select “pip_console.py”
5. Type “pip install websocket”